# understanding mload assembly function

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am learning the inline assembly in solidity, I have found the function `mload(0x40)` I am confused with what this function does. Did it reserve 4 Slot/word in memory or did it load the data stored in the address 0X40 or what?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`mload(0xAB)` loads the word (32 bytes long) located at the memory address `0xAB`. e.g `mload(0x60)` loads the word located at the `0x60` memory address.

Let's code to understand more:

```js
     function f()  
        {
            assembly {
                let freemem_pointer := mload(0x40)
                mstore(add(freemem_pointer,0x00),"36e5236fcd4c61044949678014f0d085")
                mstore(add(freemem_pointer,0x20),"36e5236fcd4c61044949678014f0d086")
                let arr1:= mload(freemem_pointer) //read first string 
                mstore(add(freemem_pointer,0x40),arr1)
            }
        }
```

After execution, `f()` generates the following memory state:
[image]

The code above stores two strings (two memory words of 32 bytes each) in the free memory space. The destination memory addresses are obtained by adding offsets of `0x00` and `0x20` (for the first and second strings respectively) to the free memory pointer address (located at the memory address `0x40` and pointing to the `0x60` address).

In the EVM, the first 4 words in the memory are reserved and the `0x40`-`0x50` memory words are allocated to the free memory pointer.

`MLOAD` and `MSTORE` are defined in detail in the Ethereum Yellow Paper:

[image]

`[a...b)` refers to the bytes of memory starting at position `a` up to (but excluding) position `b`. However, `b]` means "`b` included".

Comment: You really shouldn't just write to memory without checking the `0x40` pointer first.

Comment: What are the first 4 words used for, if the last 2 are for the free memory pointer and the length of the dynamic array?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg the first 4 are reserved for hash operations.

Comment: Thanks @AntonCheng. For posterity: go read the [Layout in Memory](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/internals/layout_in_memory.html) docs. They helped me understand this.

Comment: What tool are you using to display the memory pane? Looking for some visual tools to help me grasp the concepts of evm.

Comment: What are the numbers between the memory address and the string values? the 333665... etc. What do these values represent?

Comment: reresents the stored strings

Comment: @BadrBellaj Can you expand a little more on what those string values represent ?

Answer (score 34):

As others have stated, the `x
m:=mload(0x40)` instruction reads the 32 bytes of memory starting at position `0x40`.

In solidity, the `0x40` slot in memory is special: it contains the "free memory pointer" which points to the end of the currently allocated memory.

When you use inline assembly, you should load the data stored at `0x40` and then only write to addresses after the result. When you're done, if you want to keep that memory allocated, you should overwrite `0x40` with the new value of the free memory pointer.

Comment: Thanks for that very insightful remark. I have always been wondering why almost any contract starts with `PUSH1 60 PUSH1 40 MSTORE`, but now it makes sense, `60` is the free memory pointer.

Comment: @SCBuergel why `60`, not `40`?

Comment: Because 60 is the next free memory slot available

Answer (score 2):

Those who might be confused from the picture posted by @Badr, although I am not sure why, the memory doesn't look like it currently (version ^0.8.0). As others pointed out, the `mload(0x40)` returns where the pointer addresses that you can start using it. (free-pointer)

The first four 32 bytes (128) are always reserved when your smart contract is deployed. This is the reason your `mload(0x40)` returns 80. 80 is represented in hex format. It is 128 in decimal, which is where you can start writing in memory! This is how the memory looks like currently.

[image]

Comment: Is that picture from remix? If so, how did you generate it? Is that some sort of plugin? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, no plugin. When the transaction is created, use debug option and it will show you. https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_debug.html