# What does the assembly part of this function do? (in receiveApproval )

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, assembly

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `approveAndCall()` function, because I want to allow users to pay for functions of my main contract with the associated tokens.

I'm trying to understand the example of [this article](https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/ethereum-smart-service-payment-with-tokens-60894a79f75c). In the "**approveAndCall()**" section, the following functions are shown:

```
function approveAndCall(address _recipient,
                    uint256 _value,
                    bytes _extraData) {
  approve(_recipient, _value);
  TokenRecipient(_recipient).receiveApproval(msg.sender,
                                         _value,
                                         address(this),
                                         _extraData);
}
```

and

```
function receiveApproval(address _sender,
                         uint256 _value,
                         TokenContract _tokenContract,
                         bytes _extraData) {
  require(_tokenContract == tokenContract);
  require(tokenContract.transferFrom(_sender, address(this), 1));
  uint256 payloadSize;
  uint256 payload;
  assembly {
    payloadSize := mload(_extraData)
    payload := mload(add(_extraData, 0x20))
  }
  payload = payload >> 8*(32 - payloadSize);
  info[sender] = payload;
}
```

What does the assembly part in the second function do?

The example function stores data, so all the actual function called via the token contract does is `info[sender] = payload;`. Do I need a payload if I replace it with my function that only has "simple" arguments? (No `bytes`, just `uint`s, addresses, etc.) Do they need to be converted to `bytes`?

(I might ask a different question for more details about `approveAndCall()` and `recieveApproval`, for now I'd just want to understand that payload part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need the code related to the payload. You can modify the function and remove the bytes _exrtaData or just pass a random value there.

The `reciveApproval` just need to execute `transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value)` to move the tokens approved.

For the assembly, well, it seem to be very specific. You can see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/understanding-mload-assembly-function) about mload instruction.

mload(0xAB) loads the data stored in the location 0XAB. The instructions seem to reflect a particular application in which the contract receive a memory position (_extraData) in which information about the size of the data is stored. Then in a position _extraData + 0x20 there is the data which is modified by doing a [right shift operation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html?highlight=operators) and then the result is stored in `info` (I have no idea about the purpose of this)

I hope this helps

EDIT after OP comment.

If you will have receiveApproval behavior to depend of what the subject wants to do, you can ask them to pass an extra parameter like this:

```
function receiveApproval(address _sender, uint256 _value, TokenContract _tokenContract, string param) public {
    require(tokenContract.transferFrom(_sender, address(this), _value));
    if (param == 'your_first_code'){
        //do something
    }
    if (param == 'your_second_code'){
        //do something
    } 
    // more conditional as functions you have
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So what do I write in `receiveApproval`? I can't write instructions directly, because I want to be able to call different functions. Do I have to write as many `approveAndCall` and  `receiveApproval` as I have functions?

Comment: I updated the answer. You could have only one approveAndCall and ask for an extra parameter that defines what function should be executed in your contract. I wrote an example of this in the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So, because it's in my service contract and not my token contract, in the `if`s I can call my function directly, right? Like `if (function_code == 1) { function1(arg1, arg2); } else if (function_code == 2) { function2(arg3); }`

Comment: Yes, this is now in your contract so you can call the functions directly

Comment: A lot of things are still blurry. Is `recipient` the service contract address? If not, where do I put the contract address?

Comment: If I had a function that used `msg.sender`, can I still use it or do I have to replace it? (I assume that in the `receiveApproval()` function, `msg.sender` becomes the token contact, am I correct?)

Comment: Yes, `recipient` is the service contract address. Note that this will create a balance entry in the token contract for the service contract. So your contract service should have a function to transfer the tokens if needed.

Yes again, the msg.sender is now the token contract, however, the original sender is in receive approval as _sender

Comment: If I have answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: Yes of course, was going to. I just wanted to ask a few complementary questions because I hadn't understood everything. I think I have all I need for now :)