# Why is mstore not working here? (assembly)

Tags: assembly

```
function debug() returns (bytes) {
        bytes memory ret = new bytes(6);
        bytes memory word = new bytes(6);
        word = hex"61626f757400";
        assembly {
            mstore(add(ret, 32), word)
        }
        return ret;
}
```

returns 0x000000000000, desired outcome return 0x61626f757400

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/understanding-mload-assembly-function?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how `ret` is the location in memory of the *length* of the bytes array `ret`. It's the same with `word`, so when you do `mstore(add(ret, 32), word)`, you're actually storing the location in memory of the length of array `word` at the start of the data in the `ret` array. Here is the correct version of what you're trying to do:

```
function debug() view returns (bytes) {
    bytes memory ret = new bytes(6);
    bytes memory word = new bytes(6);
    word = hex"61626f757400";
    assembly {
        mstore(add(ret, 32), mload(add(word, 32)))
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: of course, not sure why I missed that. Thanks, great answer.